# Unwanted double underline on <abbr> elements

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

The latest version of Chrome (v58) adds a dotted underline to `<abbr>` elements:

```css
abbr[title], acronym[title] {
  text-decoration: underline dotted;
}
```

Bootstrap itself applies a dotted bottom border to `<abbr>` elements. This leads to an undesirable double-border effect:

> [image]

How can I fix this?

Comment: Thanks for posting!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This can be fixed by simply adding the following to your CSS:

```css
abbr[title] {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

I've submitted this as an issue on Bootstrap's GitHub page ([#22562](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/22562)), so hopefully Bootstrap will handle this for us in the next release.

Answer (score 1):

Either remove the `text-decoration` or the `border-bottom`.

Comment: Removing the `border-bottom` will remove the dotted line completely on browsers which do not have the dotted underline by default. If you remove the border you'll need to manually add in the `text-decoration` to ensure that is in place.

Comment: Indeed James - you'd use one or the other.